# How to create an endpoint to axios POST

Tags: vue.js, axios, endpoint

I'm currently building a Twitter-like app as a coding training in Vue.js, and have been stuck on an error `POST 404 Not Found`.

The error happens when I try to post a new tweet, whereas "show the previous tweets" function works. I'm using `axios post`for "post a new tweet" and `axios get` for "show the previous tweets". I'm using the same address `http://localhost:8080/feed.json` both for `post` and `get`.

This means that the address itself is correct, and just a few minutes ago I learned that the error for the POST is most likely because of the fact that I haven't created an endpoint for the POST.

Now here comes another problem. I don't have a good picture of how "creating an endpoint" looks like in my mind even after googling looking for some useful concrete examples.

So I want to gather some concrete information by asking the following questions.

- In what kind of file should I define the endpoint, if I want to use it for axios in Vue.js? Vue file? JavaScript file? Or some other type of file?
- Where do I define the endpoint? In the directory where there is my main `App.vue` exists? Or somewhere else?
- How does "creating an endpoint for `axios post` look like in ACTUAL CODE?
- Once the endpoint is defined, how am I supposed to use it? I mean, how does the file in which I use `axios post` recognize it? For example, in Vue.js, writing the line `import ShowPreviousTweets from './components/ShowPreviousTweets'` within the JavaScript part of the Vue file lets you use the externally defined `ShowPreviousTweets` component. Is there something corresponding to this when you want to use the externally defined endpoint?

***NOTE: I highly appreciate you if you answer my question by showing some EXAMPLE CODE via "Answer this question", rather than by just writing some sentences in the comment section. Please do include some example code in the explanation.***

**[UPDATED]**

In this program, the server side is taken care of by Node.js

[How my working directory "slutuppgift" looks like]

```
slutuppgift/
|--                         Static files
|-- index.html              HTML-code 
|-- feed.json               the API JSON-data
|-- node_modules            
|-- src/                
|-- |-- main.js             JavaScript-code to initialize Vue & app.vue
|-- |-- App.vue             Vue-code for the application
|-- |-- components/         Vue-code for components
|-- |-- views/              Vue-code for pages/templates (Vue-router).
|-- |-- router.js           JavaScript-code for Vue-router (URL-structure)
|-- |-- api.js              JavaScript-code for Express.js (the API)
```

**[UPDATED Version 2]**

[endpoint.js (in "backend" folder]

```
var express = require('express');
var endpoint = express();
var portNo = 8080;

endpoint.listen(portNo, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + portNo);
});

// Get method route
endpoint.get('/newKweet', function(req, res){
    res.send('GET request to kweet');
});

// POST method route
endpoint.post('/newKweet', function(req, res){
    res.send('POST request kweet');
})
```

**[UPDATED Version 3]**

[App.vue]

```
newKweet(){
  var self = this;
  alert(self.kweetInput);

  this.axios.post('/newKweet', {     
    userJSON: self.userJSON
    avatar: self.userJSON.avatar,
    username: self.userJSON.username,
    handle: self.userJSON.handle,
    timestamp: self.userJSON.timestamp,
    content: self.userJSON.content,
    media: {
      type: self.userJSON.media.type,
      url: self.userJSON.media.url
    },
    actions: {
      replies: self.userJSON.actions.replies,
      rekweets: self.userJSON.actions.rekweets,
      likes: self.userJSON.actions.likes
    }  
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log('The output: ');
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log('An error occured...');
    console.log(error);
  });    

  self.kweetInput = '';
  console.log('The end of newKweet() method');
}
```

**[UPDATED Version 4]**

[template part of `App.vue`]

```
<template>
    <form class = "userContainer">
        <div class = "user-avatar"> 
            <img src="avatar/avatar-loggedin.jpg">
        </div>
        <textarea rows = "10" cols = "80" v-model="kweetInput">  </textarea>  
    button class = "kwitterBtn" type = "submit" @click.prevent="newKweet()">Kwitter</button>
    </form>  
</template>
```

**[UPDATED Version 5]**

```
slutuppgift/
|--                         Static files
|-- index.html              HTML-code 
|-- feed.json               the API JSON-data
|-- node_modules   
|-- backend
|-- |-- endpoint.js         newly created endpoint according to the advice         
|-- src/                
|-- |-- main.js             JavaScript-code to initialize Vue & app.vue
|-- |-- App.vue             Vue-code for the application
|-- |-- components/         Vue-code for components
|-- |-- views/              Vue-code for pages/templates (Vue-router).
|-- |-- router.js           JavaScript-code for Vue-router (URL-structure)
|-- |-- api.js              JavaScript-code for Express.js (the API)
```

[endpoint.js]

```
var express = require('express');
var endpoint = express();

var cors = require('cors');
endpoint.use(cors());

var portNo = 3000;

endpoint.listen(portNo, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + portNo);
});

// Get method route
endpoint.get('/newKweet', function(req, res){
    res.send('GET request to kweet');
});

// POST method route
endpoint.post('/newKweet', function(req, res){
    res.send('POST request kweet');
})
```

Comment: Do you have a server running, serving the json file?

Comment: vue is a frontend framework. When you do a HTTP request (using axios for instance), that goes to a backend, say a `php` server. This backend can then accept a http method (say `POST` or `GET`) on a particular URL.

Comment: Just as the updated post, I'm using Node.js for the server side.

Comment: Have a look at [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server). It's not production-ready but for learning how to build front-ends, it will provided a REST API over your JSON data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable *cross domain request* do as following:

Install **cors** from terminal (you need to stay in the root folder of your node app):

```
npm install --save cors
```

Then in your app main js add this line after the actual module import

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
/* THE NEW PART */
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
/* ... */
```

Then retry to recall endpoint with axios

Comment: Still get the same error. And this time I also got ```xhr.js?ec6c:172 POST localhost:3000/newKweet net::ERR_FAILED``` I added updated version 5 to show the current state of ```endpoint.js``` file.

Comment: I created a replica online of your app: https://repl.it/repls/CrowdedRespectfulDegree try to call this endpoint:
https://crowdedrespectfuldegree--five-nine.repl.co/newKweet

Comment: What does this replica do? When I hit the "run" button, it produced a lot of green statements as output.

Answer (score 1):

In your main node application js  (in backend) install and run express:
(Install it with npm install —save express)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Then create all your endpoint in this way

```
// GET method route
app.get('/tweet', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to tweet');
});

// POST method route
app.post('/tweet', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request tweet');
});
```

You can use same endpoint if you have different method but you cannot have two endpoint with same method and endpoint.

---

### Update

Let's see here: https://repl.it/repls/GargantuanFaintSets

It's a basic online app that I'm done for show you how express and node work together. The app create a temporary website, now follow these links:
 - https://gargantuanfaintsets--five-nine.repl.co (home, the "/" get endpoint)
 - https://gargantuanfaintsets--five-nine.repl.co/tweet (the "/tweet" get endpoint)
 - for the post you need to use axios or a form becouse directly navigation with browser always do get call

Now on your local machina, if your app is setted correctly and you terminal is up and running the command `node app.js` (be sure to use the name of your .js main file and to run the command from the backend folder) you can navigate to this link: `http://localhost:3000/tweet`